# Where to put python module in spring boot application using Jython2.7?

Tags: spring-boot, jython-2.7

I am using the Spring boot for an Java application and I want to put a python module `my_module.py` in the the app. I am trying to import the module like

`interpretor.exec("import my_impodule")`

But I am getting the error `ImportError: No Module named my_module` and when I check the current working directory using

`interpretor.exec("import os\nprint os.getcwd()")`

which gave me the path `/my_project/` and my module location is `/my_project/my_module.py` which is correct. It should pick up the module if current working directory is this.

Can someone please help me where to put the python module so that I can picked up by Jython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Python module path. So that it can pick your module like this:

```
Properties pyProperties = new Properties();
pyProperties.put("python.path", System.getProperty("user.dir") + MODULE_PATH);
PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), pyProperties(), new String[0]);
PythonInterpreter pyInterpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
```